# Automapper, Partial map big DTO with associations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, automapper, dto

I want to map my Entities list to DTO list without associations to other DTO's.

For example:
http://mysite.local/api/documents returns list of DocumentDTO,

but request to http://mysite.local/api/documents/DA49BC12-CFAB-496A-B3D9-A26200F3E76C
returns detailed DocumentDTO object with associations, child objects.

Perhaps I should define two DTO's for my Document entity? (DocumentListItemDTO, DocumentDetailDTO). Or I can partial map my entity to dto with AutoMapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use odata also to only select the fields you need like http://mysite.local/documents?$select=Id,Name

But if you really want that list objects are different then detail objects i guess it should be different objects.